# Trying to find index of minimum value in a matrix fails in Octave

Tags: octave, minimum

So I have this matrix:

```
E1 = [54 5 2 4;4 5 19 29;31 4 2 9; 1 3 99 34]
```

lets say I want to find the location of the value closest to 18.9. let A = 18.9

I would do

```
[r,c] = find(E1==min(min(abs(E1-A))))
```

This doesn't work. It returns `r = "[](0x1)" and c = "[](0x1)"`

however,

if I first do:

`F = abs(E1-A)` and then do

```
[r,c] = find(F==min(min(F)))
```

this gives `r = 2` and `c = 3` which is correct. 19 is the closest value and 19 lives in row 2 column 3.

Why doesnt this work then? F is simply `abs(E1-A)` so why can I not put `abs(E1-A)` in place of F in the find formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
min(min(abs(E1-A)))
ans =  0.10000
```

This gives you the min over the absolute difference. Then you compare it to E1 which has absolute values. This is complete different from your second formular

```
[r,c] = find(F==min(min(F)))
```

where you comapre the minimum difference with the matrix containing the absolute of differences between E1 and A. If you replace in your second formula F with abs(E1-A) you would get

```
[r,c] = find(abs(E1-A)==min(min(abs(E1-A))))
```

Which would also work. Nevertheless I would suggest another approach:

```
E1 = [54 5 2 4;4 5 19 29;31 4 2 9; 1 3 99 34];
A = 18.9;
# get the index ( Column-major order) of the minimum
idx = nthargout (2, @min, abs (E1-A)(:));
# this returns 10
# convert it ro row, column
[r, c] = ind2sub (size (E1), idx)
r =  2
c =  3
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try. I must confess my example here is simpler than what I am working with. I am using two 61x61 matrices produced from using linspace and meshgrid commands. As such one matrix has 61 repeating rows (i.e. for given column, all rows have same value) and the other has 61 repeating columns.

So the above actually returns a whole bunch of row and column locations unless I add ,1) at the end to tell it to give me the first value found. Really I am interested in the row number from 1 matrix and the column number from the other. 

I will try your code! Looks nice!

Comment: in nthargout, what is the 2 for? I didn't quite understand what "help nthargout" had to say on the matter

Comment: @user3894764 `nathargout (2, @min, ...)` will return the second output of out `min` as if called with 2 output arguments. In this case, it's the same as `[~, idx] = min (abs (E1-A)(:))`. From this case you may think nthargout, but it's actually a very useful tool for other situations.

Comment: carandraug: I first wrote an one-liner [r, c] = ind2sub (size (E1), nthargout (2, @min, abs (E1-A)(:))); and then decided to split it. You are absolutely right that in this case [~,idx] = min (...) would be better readable.

Comment: Thansk guys! This was extremely helpful!